# How is it possible that I make my player die in unity

Tags: unity, 2d, platform

So what I have is a 2 platform game where I want my player to die when it hits a trap and go back to the last checkpoint it when past

Currently I use this script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Respawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform PlayerPrefab;
    public Transform SpawnPoint;

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision col)
     {
         if (col.gameObject.tag == "Trap")
         {
             respawn();
         }
    }
 

    void respawn()
    {
        Instantiate(PlayerPrefab, SpawnPoint.position, SpawnPoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

but When i hit the trap I go through it
The trap does have a 2 collider on it with ontrigger Selected

How could I implement a checkpoint system and then death

Comment: Add a Debug.Log("Hit trap"); before the respawn in the trigger. So we know for sure if your problem lies in the respawn (you do not destroy the current player) or in reaching to the part of respawn. And where is this respawn script attached? On the player or the trap? And you have the wrong method signatur `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)`. You are missing 2D on Collision

Comment: @Zibelas Hit trap works but I don't respawn What must I fix

Comment: PlayerPrefab should be of type `GameObject` and not `Transform`

Comment: @Zibelas now I get this error : InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
(wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)
UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at /Users/bokken/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs:281)
Respawn.respawn () (at Assets/Respawn.cs:22)
Respawn.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D other) (at Assets/Respawn.cs:15)

Comment: Well, do you have a PlayerPrefab? It is the a bluish looking cube in your project folder

Comment: @Zibelas   I re added my player to the prefab slot but I doesn't respawn but doesn't crash

Comment: Take a look at the Inspector in the scene when the game is running. Do you see one more PlayerPrefab (clone) there when you hit the trap?

Comment: @Zibelas why do I see player clone

Comment: Because Instantiate creates a new clone -> a player in this case. But your old player is still fine since you never `Destroy` it. So each time you hit your trap, you create another player. Happy Clone Wars

Comment: @Zibelas How do I destroy then and have a time delay between respawning

Comment: Well, `Destroy(YourPlayer)` should work (with YourPlayer the active prefab of the player). If this respawn script is attached to the player, you can also use `Destroy(this)`; but keep in mind once an object is gone, it can't call further code that is executed on the same GameObject (well, since it is destroyed) For a delayed calling of your respawn you can use Invoke("respawn", 3f);

Comment: @Zibelas When I use "Destroy(PlayerPrefab);" I get this "The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it."

Comment: Because PlayerPrefab is not the active player but the one from which you try to create new ones. Did you took a look at the Unity2D platform tutorial? It has a small alien shooter example that shows you how to Spawn/ Destroy elements. This is just spoon feeding.

Answer (score 1):

The Collision action matrix section of [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) is always a great reference to look at. It shows what collision detection/trigger messages are sent when two objects collide.

I would ensure that the player has a `RigidBody2D` (shouldn't matter if it's kinematic or not) and a `Collider2D` (with Trigger selected), and that the trap has a `Collider2D` (with trigger selected as well).

And the callback you should use for trigger messages is `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)`, not `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision col)`.

Comment: The last paragraph is what's definitely wrong here. The rest are things which *could* be wrong.

Comment: Another thing that is definitely wrong is that there is no GameObject used in the Instantiate but a Transform.

Comment: @Zibelas that's probably not an issue. You're allowed to Instantiate a Game Object with a reference to any of its Components, including a Transform. It still spawns the whole object, not just one free-floating Component.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks, there is always something new to learn.

Comment: Make sure to test your theories first, to avoid misleading new users. There's a lot of misinformation about Unity or GameDev in general that spreads from folks sharing rules they've heard but never tested to see if they're valid.